# Search particular node value from XML

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

This is my PHP/XML code. I just want to search the particular `$searchterm` from this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('authentication.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$searchTerm = "N0A097016646";

$lineNo = 0;
foreach ($xpath->query('//device/following::comment()') as $comment){
    $serial= $xpath->query('//device', $comment)->item($lineNo)->textContent;

    echo "Line number: ".$comment->getLineNo()." Device number: ".$serial." Comented number: ".$comment->textContent."<br>";

    $lineNo++;
}
```

Where should I put the `$searchTerm` variable to search that particular node?

Comment: use your `$searchTerm` inside your xpath query, its not used. research about `contains()`

Comment: I tried it,
but doesn't work :
$serial= $xpath->query('//device[contains("'.$searchTerm.'")]', $comment)->item($lineNo)->textContent;

Comment: do you have a sample xml to work with? hard to guess on this end

Comment: Hi, Yes,
and also I no need to use that $lineNo variable. but when I remove, it will show some error. I can get line number using getLineNo() function,
this is my sample xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
<appConfig authenticate="true"></appConfig> <!-- Can have values "true" or "false" to activate/deactivate SN verification to launch app-->
 <!-- Production Serial Numbers-->
<device>J0A0AM049303</device> <!-- 100001 -->
<device>H0A0AG014628</device> <!-- 100002 -->
<device>N0A097016646</device> <!-- 100003 -->
</rss>

Answer (score 1):

As your question stands you haven't use the `$searchTerm`.

Use it with `=` (equal)

```
text() = '$searchTerm'
```

Code:

```
$searchTerm = "N0A097016646";

foreach ($xpath->query("//device[text() = '$searchTerm']/following::comment()") as $comment){
    echo "Line number: ".$comment->getLineNo(). '<br/>'.
    " Device number: ".$searchTerm.'<br/>'.
    " Comented number: ". $comment->textContent."<hr>";
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/I9Tgn1)

Comment: Hi,
but I only want 1 result according to that $searchTerm; but this shows everything again. please help to resolve it
this is my xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="search.yahoo.com/mrss/">; <appConfig authenticate="true"></appConfig> <!-- Can have values "true" or "false" to activate/deactivate SN verification to launch app--> <!-- Production Serial Numbers--> <device>J0A0AM049303</device> <!-- 100001 --> <device>H0A0AG014628</device> <!-- 100002 --> <device>N0A097016646</device> <!-- 100003 --> </rss>

Comment: @user3619039 and also be wary of xpath injection also if this a user input http://dl.packetstormsecurity.net/papers/attack/xpath-injection.pdf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188834/cleaning-sanitizing-xpath-attributes