# What did they find on my site test" and 1=0] | //* | /*["0")

Tags: xml, xpath

I found out someone performed  '  test" and 1=0] | //* | /*["0") ' on my site, this looks like XPATH since I use XML on my site but what does it actually mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [XPath injection attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XPATH_Injection) which tried to get all of the nodes in the document recursively (the `//*` part). To understand, what happened, better go through an example.

Imagine you dynamically construct an XPath expression to search the `subnode` values by text which is entered by a user. XML document that you use:

```
<root>
    <node>
        <subnode>value1</subnode>
        <subnode>value2</subnode>
    </node>
</root>
```

And, you have this expression: `//node[. = "%s"]` where `%s` is a placeholder for the value entered by a user. A user might enter `value1` which would produce `//node[. = "value1"]` expression which is perfectly safe and would return `<subnode>value1</subnode>`, okay.

But now, imagine if a user would enter `test" and 1=0] | //* | /*["0` query, you would get `//node[. = " test" and 1=0] | //* | /*["0"]` which is also syntactically correct but, in this case, a user would get all of the nodes including `root`, `node` and `subnodes` accessing what a user was not supposed to access.

Let's break down the `//node[. = " test" and 1=0] | //* | /*["0"]` expression. The attacker used `test" and 1=0]` part to get out of the existing condition and make it match nothing adding the `1=0` condition. `|` means "or" in XPath. The `//*` would recursively match every node in the document - this is what gives the attacker what he/she was up to. The `/*["0` part is needed to keep the expression syntactically correct and balance the quotes.

---

There are several ways to prevent it from happening, summarized [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XPATH_Injection#Related_Controls):

- sanitize/validate the user input. Least you can do is to *escape the quotes*
- use *pre-compiled* XPath expressions:

> Precompiled XPaths are already preset before the program executes, rather than created on the fly after the user's input has been added to the string. This is a better route because you don't have to worry about missing a character that should have been escaped

- use *parameterized* XPath expressions:

> Parameterization causes the input to be restricted to certain domains, such as strings or integers, and any input outside such domains is considered invalid and the query fails.

See also:

- [How to prevent XPath/XML injection in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381689/how-to-prevent-xpath-xml-injection-in-net)
- [Cleaning/sanitizing xpath attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188834/cleaning-sanitizing-xpath-attributes?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, any idea's how to make sure this can't happen anymore?

Comment: @AlexBouttelgier okay, sure, updated the answer with some more information and links.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'm the networking guy so I'll give it to the guy that takes care of the website it's his problem now ;) thanks a lot for helping me I really appreciate it.